# Can anyone explain a weird behavior for paste on character(0)?

Tags: r

The question itself is clear:

If you paste a character(0) with some string, it will automatic disappear,the code and the result is below:

```
paste(paste(NULL,character(0),sep = "\n"),character(0),sep = "\n")
character(0)
```

However,if you wrap the character(0) with list, then then code and result is:

```
paste(paste(NULL,list(character(0)),sep = "\n"),list(character(0)),sep = "\n")
[1] "\ncharacter(0)\ncharacter(0)"
```